# If I install phonegap, will I have problems with Xcode in the future?

Tags: xcode, cordova

I am an engineer but I don't have any development background. My boss gave me a Mac Mini with Xcode in it, and looks like someone sent me some source code to be used with phonegap.

So my question is, if I install (?) phonegap, will I be able to use Xcode in a normal way in the future, or is it an irreversible process that changes Xcode completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not affect Xcode at all. Now, you will just be able to select the phonegap application type when creating a new Xcode project if that is what you want to use.

Comment: So if I have any other source code written just for Xcode, phonegap will not add any other stuff automatically, right?

Comment: @whySoSerious PhoneGap will not mess around with other Xcode projects.

Comment: Correct, only Phonegap projects.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to have a look on that, under "Phonegap Generate" : http://savagelook.com/blog/portfolio/8-things-to-know-about-phonegap

And on that too : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/VE9EiD-eIrY

Answer (score 0):

why So Serious,

You can user the xCode as is since the moment you intalled phonegap.

Do not panic and enjoy coding.

Thanks,
Jigar

Comment: What if I decide not to use phonegap anymore? My system will be "clean" for apple standards?

Comment: @whySoSerious Yes, PhoneGap is just a library. Don't worry it won't break Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes! If you install it you will be lost forever :D Just joking! Go on! 
Nothing wrong will happen, consider take a look at the documentation before start doing things...